# Error using .overlayWith() on AWS Lambda in node.js sharp

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sharp

I'm using sharp on AWS Lambda, and it works pretty good, but, when I try to add watermark, it gives an error.

```
The input file is missing or of an unsupported image format
```

It works fine on local but on AWS lambda; it gives this error

```
function watermarkLogo(buffer, last) {
              sharp(buffer)
                .overlayWith('watermark.png', { gravity: sharp.gravity.center } )
                .toBuffer(versions[ind].format, function(err, buffer) {
                  if (err) last(err);
                  else last(null, buffer);
                });
          }
```

Watermark and lambda function are in same bucket

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/yallamotor-development-assets/watermark.png

How can I solve this

Comment: May be 'watermark.png' file is missing, you can recheck on AWS console and make sure that the file is exist.

Comment: @hoangdv i check again its there. I update question and give link also

Comment: Hix, Your Lambda function will be store in a Node container (for your case), thus the code will not get your file. The s3 bucket only store your lambda code, when you create/update a lambda function with of `Code entry type` with option `Upload a file from Amazon S3`  (Upload :D) , System just make a copy of the code (without your image). You can make a zip file include code and image then upload to your lambda function (or s3). You can see anythings at https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda

Answer (score 2):

To add watermark you can use `composite()`.

```
    let sharp = require('sharp');
    let imageBuffer = null;

    await sharp(buffer)
        .composite([{ input: './watermark.png', gravity: 'center' }])
        .sharpen()
        .withMetadata()
        .toBuffer()
        .then(function(outputBuffer) {
            imageBuffer = outputBuffer;
        });

return imageBuffer;
```

And you can get watermarke with FTP and buffer then, and you pass the buffer in `composite`.